# Converting Matlab code to a static C++ library

Tags: c++, matlab, static-libraries, converters

what's the best way to convert Matlab code to a static C/C++ library

Comment: For the reference take a look in this [library](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Matlab Coder](http://www.mathworks.nl/products/matlab-coder/) or [Matlab Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/) to convert MATLAB Code into static libraries.

Comment: I would like to ask if the coder works for any matlab code, independently how much complex the matlab code is and how complex it became in C++. I other words, what is preferable, hand made or automatic generation? Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I think I found [it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940669/matlab-coder-vs-hand-coding).

Comment: Matlab Coder was not previously called Matlab Compiler. There are two similar products. Note: All code are, MATLAB Compiler friendly, not MATLAB Coder friendly.

Comment: @LokeshA.R. In the 2006 to 2010a versions I have, there is no Coder available, and the Compiler that comes with it does exactly what the description of the Coder is on the website, while the (current) description of the Compiler looks like more a packaging tool. Hence my confusion

Comment: @damienfrancois: No problem, I had thought that you might be using an older version of MATLAB. I have updated your answer.